# JavaScript change text anchor link iOS 8.1

Tags: javascript, ios

I have the following JavaScript, that used to work everywhere, and now works everywhere but iOS 8.1.

Anyone know a solution to get this actually working everywhere again?

```
<a href="http://someurl.com" onclick="this.style.color='grey'; this.innerHTML='Please wait...';">Press Me</a>
```

It simply changes the text color and value when the link is clicked, no biggie, but iOS 8 seems to have broken it.

The link still works, but the text never changes.

If I add a

```
return false;
```

At the end of the onclick, the text changes, but obviously the link does not get followed.